# Getting "Invalid Syntax" Error When Code is run on Python 3.9.4 Command line

Tags: python, pycharm, interpreter

The following simple program runs fine in my Pycharm editor but I keep getting "Invalid syntax" errors when I run the same code directly on my Python 3.6.4 command line. See screenshot. [image: Screenshot] Please help identify the issue.

```py
def lucky_number(name):
  number = len(name) * 9
  print("Hello " + name + ". Your lucky number is " + str(number))
lucky_number(“Kay”)
lucky_number(“Cameron”)
```

Comment: Do you see the three dots on the left? When you type a function in REPL (your console), you need to Enter two times to effectively define your block - that can be a function, a for loop, and so on

Comment: @crissal this is the correct solution. you should post as an answer...

Comment: @Aaron ok, I did it, I thought just a comment will do it

Comment: @crissal comments don't get indexed for google searchability... SO still tries somewhat to be a historic repository of canonical answers rather than just a temporary Q&A platform.

Comment: @Aaron ok, thank you, I didn't know about comments indexing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you see the three dots on the left? When you type a function in REPL (your console), you need to Enter two times to effectively define your block - that can be a function, a for loop, and so on.

By the way, in your posted code there are smart quotes, that as other said, can lead to a SyntaxError; but in your screenshot looks fine, so probably there was a problem with typing them on StackOverflow.

Comment: You're right @crissal. The code runs fine when I pressed the Enter/return key twice to after the third line. I only started using the Python CMD a few hours ago. I have been using Pycharm for months on the other hand.

Comment: Perfect @ApexResources; by the way, when you find the correct answer, you should mark it as accepted. You can find more on ["What should I do when someone answers my question?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) or, in general, in the [Help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help).

Answer (score 0):

You can try changing the quotes (“Kay” by "Kay")

```
lucky_number("Kay")
lucky_number("Cameron")
```

Answer (score 0):

Change “Kay” to "Kay" and “Cameron” to "Cameron"

(Error Reason: Python don't understand different style quotes)

Comment: iirc this would generate a slightly different error